# can't figure out how to update my pip version to 23.2.1

Tags: python, pip

I did almost everything but I don't know what to do more...
is there anyone who can figure out why? and what should I do to update my pip...

**I just typed this:**

```
C:\Users\SAMSUNG\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311> python -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

**then**

```
ERROR: Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\SAMSUNG\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\base_command.py", line 160, in exc_logging_wrapper
    status = run_func(*args)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\SAMSUNG\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\req_command.py", line 247, in wrapper
    return func(self, options, args)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\SAMSUNG\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\pip\_internal\commands\install.py", line 494, in run
    installed = install_given_reqs(
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\SAMSUNG\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\pip\_internal\req\__init__.py", line 73, in install_given_reqs
    requirement.install(
  File "C:\Users\SAMSUNG\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\pip\_internal\req\req_install.py", line 792, in install
    install_wheel(
  File "C:\Users\SAMSUNG\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\pip\_internal\operations\install\wheel.py", line 729, in install_wheel
    _install_wheel(
  File "C:\Users\SAMSUNG\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\pip\_internal\operations\install\wheel.py", line 646, in _install_wheel
    generated_console_scripts = maker.make_multiple(scripts_to_generate)
                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\SAMSUNG\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\pip\_vendor\distlib\scripts.py", line 436, in make_multiple
    filenames.extend(self.make(specification, options))
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\SAMSUNG\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\pip\_internal\operations\install\wheel.py", line 427, in make
    return super().make(specification, options)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\SAMSUNG\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\pip\_vendor\distlib\scripts.py", line 425, in make
    self._make_script(entry, filenames, options=options)
  File "C:\Users\SAMSUNG\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\pip\_vendor\distlib\scripts.py", line 325, in _make_script
    self._write_script(scriptnames, shebang, script, filenames, ext)
  File "C:\Users\SAMSUNG\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\pip\_vendor\distlib\scripts.py", line 249, in _write_script
    launcher = self._get_launcher('t')
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\SAMSUNG\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\pip\_vendor\distlib\scripts.py", line 404, in _get_launcher
    raise ValueError(msg)
ValueError: Unable to find resource t64.exe in package pip._vendor.distlib

[notice] A new release of pip available: 22.3.1 -> 23.2.1
[notice] To update, run: python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip
```